# Flot Graph TickLabel and Tick Positioning Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, graph, charts, flot

I have been using FLOT for many great things. Recently, i have needed to use it for time based plots. It worked perfect last month, but this month, i noticed that my last tick was smaller than the others. Also, i noticed that the tick label was not there.

Here is a [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/hZ2n5/) of the issue for you to look at.

Due to the large amount of Javascript,  i will keep all the code inside the Fiddle; unless the information is requested.

However, me and a friend thought of a simple workaround :

```
if(% 2 === 0) {
   /*
     Check if the data can be divided by 2
     Repeat this for 3 as well (return the value and 
     plug it in the tickSize: [val, 'day'];
  */
}
```

The only drawback i see here if for months that have `31` days.

How would i fix this issue, or what did i do wrong that is causing this effect?

Comment: Could you clarify what the problem is, and what you expect to see?

Comment: @DNS Sure. How can i plot 31, 30, 28 etc. days on the graph and make it look good. I would like all the ticks to be the same size, unlike the last tick on the jsfiddle graph i showed. Instead of removing the last tick, is there a way i could remove the first AND the last tick if this was to occur? I would like everything to look neat and even on the graph.

Answer (score 0):

How about always making the chart 31 days wide (which means 30 days between first and last day and 15 ticks each 2 days wide)? You get that by setting the x axis maximum if your month does not have 31 days by itself:

```
xaxis: {
    mode: "time",
    timeformat: "%b %d",
    tickSize: [2, 'day'],
    max: 1398902400000
},
```

See this updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hZ2n5/1/).